# Not a valid month in the SQL database notebad++ i try everything but i do not how to solve these

Tags: sql

```
create table fiingerprint  
(
    device_number number (5) primary key ,
    HR_officenum number(3),
    finger_print blob  ,
    Entry_time timestamp ,
    leaving_time timestamp 
);

insert into fingerprintt 
values (13478, 123, 'C:\Users\user\Pictures', TO_DATE('09-DEC-90 12:56 A.M.','DD-MON-YY HH:MI A.M.'), TO_DATE('09-jan-90 12:56 A.M.','DD-MON-YY HH:MI A.M.'));
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, the datatype `timestamp` is not what you are looking for. (I suspect this applies to other RDBMSes, too.)

You'll want to use one of the "datetime" datatypes. There are several different such datatypes, and what you have available depends on which version of the product you are using.

(In SQL Server, the `timestamp` datatype has nothing to do with dates or times. Whatever RDBMS you are using, you need to read the documentation--or any of a n
ear-infinite number of online articles--on this and the "datetime" datatypes.)

Comment: I am student and i have this project and yes i use SQL wite nodebad++

Comment: In your script, try replacing the two instances of `timestamp` with `datetime`. (You will need to drop and recreate table "fiingerprint" for these changes to take effect.)